# Unexpected size for virtual tables

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm studing C++ inheritance and so I wrote this code:

```
// 08 Diamond Inheritance 02.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//   I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SuperVirtual
{
public:
    int sv;
    SuperVirtual(int p1 = 11) : sv(p1)
    {
        cout << "\n SuperVirtual ctor for &" << this;
    }

    virtual void methodSuperVirtual_01()
    {
        cout << "\n Inside SuperVirtual::methodSuperVirtual_01(): sv = " << ++sv;
    }

    virtual void methodSuperVirtual_02()
    {
        cout << "\n Inside SuperVirtual::methodSuperVirtual_02(): sv = " << ++sv;
    }
};

//---------------------------------- 
class DerivedSV_01 : public SuperVirtual
{
public:
    int dsv;
    DerivedSV_01(int p1 = 21) : dsv(p1)
    {
        cout << "\n DerivedSV_01 ctor for &" << this;
    }
    virtual void methodSuperVirtual_01() override
    {
        cout << "\n Inside DerivedSV_01::methodSuperVirtual_01()";
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    virtual void onlyForDerivedSV_01()
    {
        cout << "\n Inside DerivedSV_01::onlyForDerivedSV_01()";
    }
};

int main()
{
    SuperVirtual sv1(1);
    sv1.methodSuperVirtual_01();

    DerivedSV_01 dsv_01;
    dsv_01.methodSuperVirtual_01();
    dsv_01.onlyForDerivedSV_01();

    return 0;
}
```

I had read that:

> Whenever a class itself contains virtual functions or overrides virtual functions from a parent class the compiler builds a vtable for that class. The vtable contains function pointers that point to the virtual functions in that class. There can only be one vtable per class, and all objects of the same class will share the same vtable.

At this point, I supposed that the virtual table of class `SuperVirtual` contains 2 elements, while the virtual table for class `DerivedSV_01` contains 3 elements: 2 for inherited (and eventually ovverridden) methods + 1 for the new virtual method `onlyForDerivedSV_01()`.

However, inspecting the objects created in `main()` with the Visual Studio Debugger, I found that:

1. virtual table for instance of class `SuperVirtual` contains 2 elements (OK !)
2. virtual table for instance of class `DerivedSV_01` contains 2 elements (**Why ?**)

For completeness of information, I provide the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: There is no "diamont inheritance" as mentioned in your code. Is that even a [mcve]?

Comment: Why 3? There is only 2 virtual functions defined in the derived class... Only overriden ones are necessary

Comment: The vtable is a implementation detail. A given C++ implementation is not guaranteed/required to use vtable, it can do whatever it wants as long as the standard specified behaviour is obtained. And even if it *does* use a vtable, you cannot make assumptions about its implementation/size.

Comment: `DerivedSV_01` contains a `SuperVirtual`, that is what allows a `DerivedSV_01` object to be assigned to a `SuperVirtual` pointer/reference. In your screenshot, you are looking at the `SuperVirtual` portion of `DerivedSV_01`'s vtable, that is why you only see 2 entries, for `methodSuperVirtual_01` and `_02`. Vtables in derived classes are more complex than your screenshot is showing you.

Comment: What are the reasons for the downvotes? Surely this is about implementation defined behaviour, but nevertheless the question is clear and good and it is not obvious why the compiler behaves as it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this with exactly your code in VS2019 when compiling in debug mode (compiler optimization turned off). I am quite sure this is only a display issue in the debugger window.

[image: locals window]

Please note that the `__vfptr` array is only displayed under `SuperVirtual`, not directly under `dsv_01`, so of course the debugger only knows about the functions in a `SuperVirtual` vtable.

But if you look at the `Value` column for the `__vfptr`, you'll notice that in `SuperVirtual::'vftable'[3]` and `DerivedSV_01::'vftable[4]'` (both marked green) different array sizes are given.

Let's take a look at the memory at the vftables (the addresses of the vftables can be seen at the start of the `Value` column for the `__vfptr` entries and are marked orange and red).
[image: memory window]
[image: memory window]

You'll notice that `SuperVirtual::'vftable'[3]` has two function pointers (marked brown) and a `nullptr`. `DerivedSV_01::'vftable[4]'` has three pointers (marked purple and blue) and a `nullptr`. The debugger window tells us what the first two entries are (also marked purple), but take a look at the third entry in the watch window (marked blue).

[image: watch window]

The debugger says that the third entry is the `DerivedSV_01::onlyForDerivedSV_01`. That totally matches your (and my) expectations.

Comment: "[...]Let's take a look at the memory at the vftables [...]"  I can't figure out how you obtained those blocks of memory using VS. Can you help me with a short explanation ? Thank you.

Comment: @openyourmind In the local window I looked at the `__vfptr` entries and there at the address given at the start of the `Value` column.

Comment: @openyourmind I added some colours to the images to make it more clear. Same colour in different images are for the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simple "AS IF" rule kicked in.

Compiler figure out that `onlyForDerivedSV_01` is never used in polymorphic way (since there is no sub-classes of `DerivedSV_01`), so it has been converted to regular method.

So as result you have only two virtual methods inherited form base class.

In fact with full optimization enabled compiler should be able to remove all virtual calls for this code. [Here you can see](https://godbolt.org/z/CPw_X2) all methods are placed directly in `main` function and only virtual calls are performed on `std::cout`.

Comment: Additionally, declaring a class `final` can sometimes help the compiler do that optimization.

Comment: Did you also test with no optimization!?